# Python : Text Analytics

Tags: python

Suppose we have 100 news journals or articles as document revolving around businesses. Now we have find the person and its associated organisation with it. One can proceed by seeing the frequency of that person name with the company name and thus those having highest frequency will be given that tag. 
Is there any other simple and appropriated way of such ??

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please post code block where you are facing problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand completely what do you want, but maybe defaultdict is what you are looking for:

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = 'mississippi'
d = defaultdict(int)
for k in s:
    d[k] += 1

d.items() 
[('i', 4), ('p', 2), ('s', 4), ('m', 1)]
```

When a letter is first encountered, it is missing from the mapping, so the default_factory function calls int() to supply a default count of zero. The increment operation then builds up the count for each letter.

So you will have to do something similar. You will have a list of persons. Whenever you encounter that person in the text you add him/her to the defaultdict and increase the counter associated with him/her. So in the end you will have a dict with persons as keys and frequencies as values.